# Backbone routes: include a variable with only two permitted values?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'd like to write a backbone route with a variable that can only take two values. In the example below, I'd like *only* routes starting `/ca/...` or `/us/...` to be routed to handleByCountry.

Do I need to use a regex? This is the current code:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
          ":country/:str": "handleByCountry", // country should only be 'ca' or 'us'
      },
      handleByCountry: function(country, str){
          // handle 'ca' and 'us' values differently
      },
  });
```

Comment: http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/12/regex-routing-with-backbone-js/ explains how to use regexes, but not in a parameterized way (i.e. how to get the value of the regex).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it should work fine. You just have to show an error message to the user in `handleByCountry` if `country` does not equal `ca` or `us`.

Comment: OK, thanks very much! Do you know how I can get the value of `country` inside `handleByCountry`, though? I guess I can do something hacky to retrieve the route again and split it by backslashes, but is there a neater way?

Comment: If you have it dynamic like in your example (`":country/:str"`) it would just be the first parameter passed to `handleByCountry`.